# Редактирование github pages локально

Tags: git, github

Я хотел бы локально править github pages, т. е. редактировать как обычно локально и выгружать изменения обычным образом git. Как такое можно сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Склонируйте репозиторий (очевидно, но мало ли; используется для демонстрации мой репозиторий https://github.com/v1993/eiforia.git):

```
git clone https://github.com/v1993/eiforia.git
```

Создайте локально ветку gh-pages:

```
git branch gh-pages
```

Переключитесь на свежесозданную ветку:

```
git checkout gh-pages
```

Пометьте ветку для отслеживания (синхронизации):

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/gh-pages
```

Синхронизируйте HEAD и коммиты с удалённой веткой:

```
git reset --hard origin/gh-pages
```

Убедитесь, что всё сделали правильно:

```
git branch -vv
```

В выводе последней команды должна быть строка:

```
* gh-pages 3d79c21 [origin/gh-pages] Create gh-pages branch via GitHub
```

Вместо "Create gh-pages branch via GitHub" может быть другое имя, если вы уже создавали свои коммиты на этой ветке.

Comment: Если локально создавать, то вроде бы не должно быть такого имени коммита. Такое выставляет гитхаб при создании ветки через его интерфейс.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, в конце я написал "Вместо "Create gh-pages branch via GitHub" может быть другое имя, если вы уже создавали свои коммиты на этой ветке."

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно выполнить

```
git checkout gh-pages
```

а гит сделает всю оставшуюся работу за вас.